# C++, OpenGL - Сливание цвета текстуры с цветом фигуры

Tags: c++, opengl

Написал на OpenGL-е код текстуры, когда я текстуру отдельно показываю то всё хорошо идёт а когда я рисую другую фигуру вместе с текстурой, на пример квадарат и цвет квадрата синий, то текстура окрашываеться в синий цвет!

Код загрузки текстуры:

```
texture=IMG_Load(path.c_str());

if(texture->format->BitsPerPixel>=4)
    mode=GL_RGBA;
else
    mode=GL_RGB;

id=currentCount;
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[currentCount]);
currentCount++;

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mode, texture->w, 
    texture->h, 0, mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture->pixels);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, param);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, param);
```

Код показа текстуры:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-position.x, -position.y, 0);

    glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[id]);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); sprite.getPoint(0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); sprite.getPoint(1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); sprite.getPoint(2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); sprite.getPoint(3);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
```

Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так всё верно, в вашем примере кода этого нет, но по сути, вы говорите OpenGL - "приготовься, сейчас вот эти полигоны я буду рисовать синим" и как ни странно, и безтекстурные, и текстурные пиксели рисуются одинаково синими. Только в случае с текстурой, берётся её синий канал.

Тут уж либо рисуйте раздельно разными цветами, либо синий квадрат тоже из синих пикселей текстуры берите и рисуйте всё "белым".